# Tkinter entry get() problem, not updating when enter new value

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry

IN My early post:
[earlypost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77060704/tkinter-entry-get-row-like-active-cell-in-excel)

Bryan's answer is the key to do a new calculation with new entries values but when i use

```
entriesPreserv1 = []
for i in range(5,20):
    varlayer1press=tk.StringVar()
    b = tk.Entry(newtab1, textvariable=varlayer1press,background='#87CEEB')
    b.grid(row=i, column=4,sticky= 'NSEW')
    entriesPreserv1.append(varlayer1press)

focused_entry = root.focus_get()
info = focused_entry.grid_info()
rowget = info['row']
columnget = info['column']    
mpres=entriesPreserv1[rowget].get()"
```

the variabe  mpres isn't updating and keeps printing the first calculation "number". do i have to update the root??, or delete and trace_add again, I use a button to get grid info by the way. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mpres`  will never auto-update because it's just a normal python variable. If you want an updated value you'll have to call `get` again, either on the widget or the associated variable.

Comment: but thats what im doing in the last line@BryanOakley

Comment: @Orlando You are calling that line of code just once, and immediately after you create the entry widgets.

Comment: Indeed, I dont know what happened, how i missed that. Thanks Bryan